# Badge for bower dependencies on github

Tags: github, npm, bower, badge

On github it is possible to show a badge about the status of your npm dependencies ( https://david-dm.org/ )

I was wondering if there is something like this for bower dependencies ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is. [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/) supports showing dependency status for Bower packages (along with npm and some other package managers). Like David, it is free for open source GitHub projects and supports readme badges.

## Adding a Gemnasium badge

If you haven't already, set up your project on Gemnasium and open its page. Now open Settings (the gear on the right), click Badge, and copy the badge code of your choice to your project's readme.

Comment: Looks great. I've added my projects and I do see these statuses, but it doesn't seem to have badges, am I right ?

Comment: They do have badges, you just have to hunt for them. I added instructions to my answer.